# Screen Resolution changing element's width?

Tags: css

I have a fairly simple website layout thus far and notice that if I change the screen resolution in my browser, some of the widths I had specified for certain  elements change.

From other questions I've read, people have found a fix in specifying widths by pixels and not percentages. I have done this but the width continues to change by 1-3 pixels each time I change resolution?

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I unfortunately do not have the code in question with me so I will do my best to provide examples if needed.

Thanks all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use HTML like this.

```
<div style="width:950px">
<div class="wrapper"><!--all content goes here--></div>
</div>
```